# Inspiration for a report browser

Tags: web-app, information, reports

We are building a web report browser as part of our restaurant management system.

Something like this: [image: report browser example]

Not being a designer, I'm finding it quite hard to design web pages that lists our reports.

Where can I find help/inspiration/information/examples etc that would help me build a useful attractive report browser?

Answer (score 2):

Here are 2 links after a quick research with the keywords "Table UI"

http://semantic-ui.com/collections/table.html

http://www.noupe.com/design/better-ui-design-proper-use-of-tables.html